# How to access raw apiblueprint markdown?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

Given some API documentation `docs.someurl.apiary.io` (like http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io), is there some way to see the non formated source api blueprint markdown with something like `source.themoviedb.apiary.io` ?

I think it could be useful for beginners like me to consult the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet, because we need to update Terms of Service to allow sharing of non-private repositories.

However, it should be soon—we just need to communicate it properly.

Comment: Supe! I will. I thing it will also be worth a blog post.

Comment: As there could be a commented, non official, part of the api in the source, I think that the user should agree (even for public API). I can see two possibilities for the agreement :  
 - 'agree to publish the coments'  
or  
 - 'agree to publish the source'  
In my opinion it is better to ask him for the first agreement only, as it is a public API.